# Can't create a list of structs

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int x;
    struct data *next;
};

typedef struct data d_t;


/*  Main fuction  */
int main(){

    int x;
    d_t  test , *root , *head;
    scanf("%d" , &x);

    /*   Sets pointer values */
    root=&test;
    head=root;
    head->next=NULL;

    /*   While fuction represends "ADD struct to list"  */
     while(x==1){


    /* Allocating memory for new struct */
    head=(d_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_t));
    head->x=1;
    printf("%d\n" , head->x);

    /* Sets pointer values for next struct  */
    head->next=head;
    head->next=NULL;

   /* Scanfs 'x' to see if user wants to continue */
   scanf("%d" , &x);
}

    /* Prints Whole list */
    while(root!=NULL){
    printf("%d --> " , root->x);
    root=root->next;    
    }

     return 0;
 }
```

The programm should prints: `1 --> 1 --> 1---> until NULL`. Something goes wrong probably. Thank in advance!

Comment: Please learn [how to properly format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C, and try stepping through the code in a debugger. It is one of the primary tools a developer has for tracking down problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the conventional way of building a linked list:

```
int main() {
  int x;
  d_t *root, *head; // you don't need "test"
  scanf("%d", &x);
  head = NULL;
  while (x == 1) {
    root = (d_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_t));
    root->x = 1;
    root->next = head;
    head = root;
    scanf("%d", &x);
  }
  root = head;
  while (root) {
    printf("%d\n", root->x);
    root = root-> next;
  }
}
```

Analyze the first while loop. The list is being added from tail to head, starting with head = NULL.
root creates a single struct, and head becomes the previous value of root, and then it is subsequently appended to the new root value.

Output :

```
1->1->1->..etc...-> NULL
```

Comment: the start of the list would be root. Right after the while loop, I make root = head, root now represents the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
head->next=head;
head->next=NULL;
```

Is clearly not doing what you are intending. It is setting the next of the `head` to be the `head` itself, and then setting it back to `NULL`. So effectively, at each iteration you are creating a new struct and setting it's `next` to be NULL, and the previous node is getting lost. Instead of working with just single `head` variable, introduce a new one which you will allocate, assign it to `head->next`, and then switch the `head` to be the next node.

Comment: Maybe                                                                              `head=head->next;                                                                                        head->next=NULL;`                                                             is the correct?

Comment: Why won't you try? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data 
{
    int x;
    struct data *next;
};

typedef struct data d_t;

int main( void )
{
    d_t *head = NULL;
    d_t **current = &head;
    int x;

    while ( scanf( "%d" , &x ) == 1 && x == 1 )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( d_t ) );
        ( *current )->x = x;
        ( *current )->next = NULL;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }       

    /* Prints Whole list */
    for ( current = &head; *current != NULL; *current = ( *current )->next )
    {
        printf( "%d --> " , ( *current )->x );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
1 1 1 1 1 2
```

then output will be

```
1 --> 1 --> 1 --> 1 --> 1 -->
```

I used your approach to add a new node to the tail of the list though the code could look simpler if you would add each new node to the head of the list.